# How to upgrade from Entity Framework 4.3 to EF 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity, entity-framework-5

Currently we are working on the EF 4.3 . We would like to upgrade it to EF5. I have google the upgrade process steps, but I did not get any result. Please help me..!

Thanks.. :)

Comment: A bit too convoluted (for me) to write up here, but maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj618295.aspx) will help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are two links for you of content I've created on EF4.3 to EF5:

article: Moving Existing Projects to EF 5
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj618295.aspx

video: Entity Framework 5 Enums and Moving Solution from EF 4.3
http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/video-entity-framework-5-enums-and-moving-solution-from-ef-4-3/

hth
julie

Comment: Thanks Julie, I have changed the EF4 to EF5. But in EF5 there are many methods and properties are missing eg: AcceptAllChanges(), Connection.Close(), AddObject(), DeleteObject() etc. Did I miss anything..?

Comment: It sounds like you are making two more shifts here. The first is that you're using the DbContext instead of the ObjectContext. T&e second is that you are using vs2012 which makes DbContext the default generated code from EF designer. Is that correct? If yes, then although DbContext is easier with new apps, you probably want to tell the designer to use the ObjectContext template. Check this msdn topic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556581

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This solution will solve my issue, But i have to know that why microsoft 
used default as DbContext instead of ObjectContext in VS2012. I afraid that, If I am going 
back to "EF5 with ObjectContext", will I get the same performace as we expected ..? I have read
your post->http://www.devproconnections.com/article/entity-framework/entity-framework-5-143875 
about the Query performance. But more over the Query Performance can i get all EF5 features as it is..?

Comment: Athoughthis is straying from an so q&a, DbContext has been their recommendation for new projects since 4.1 was released so they made the designer in vs2012 follow tht guidance. Dbcontext is just an abstraction of objectcontext. So the benefits that are in .net4.5 I.e. enums, perf, spatial type support, are all there even with ObjectContext.