# Having trouble with entity to make sql queries

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-applications, entity

I am following this tutorial and I have no idea how to use Entity SQL: or Native SQL. Can someone help?

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx

When I try to run the code provided, after having changed the lightblue text to something matching my project, I keep getting:

> Error  1   'foo.PMEntities' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteStoreCommand' and no extension >method 'ExecuteStoreCommand' accepting a first argument of type 'foo.PMEntities' could be found (are you >missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

ExecuteStoreQuery and CreateQuery also have the same issue.

I looked at my references and I think things should be fine.

[image: a busy cat]

I can query with linq to entities just fine but I'm not very used to Linq.

Example code: 
`public ActionResult CharlieTest()
        {
            using (var objCtx = new PMEntities())
            {
                var schoolCourse = from cs in objCtx.Courses
                                   where cs.CourseName == "Course1"
                                   select cs;
                //"Cours" correlates to a course
                Cours mathCourse = schoolCourse.FirstOrDefault();
                IList courseList = schoolCourse.ToList();

```
            string courseName = mathCourse.CourseName;
        }

        //Querying with Object Services and Entity SQL
        //Entity SQL does not recognize certain statements like createQuery and I can't add a reference to something that will help
        //using (var objCtx = new PMEntities())
        //{
        //    string sqlString = "SELECT VALUE cs FROM SchoolDBEntities.Courses AS cs WHERE cs.CourseName == 'Maths'";
        //    ObjectQuery<Cours> course = objCtx.
        //        <Cours>(sqlString);
        //    Cours coursename1 = course.FirstOrDefault<Cours>();
        //}


        //nativeSQL also doesn't work. Can not find ExecuteStoreCommand or ExecuteStoreQuery
        using (var objCtx = new PMEntities())
        {
            //Inserting Student using ExecuteStoreCommand
            int InsertedRows = objCtx.Database.SqlQuery("Insert into Student(StudentName,StandardId) values('StudentName1',1)").ToArray();

            //Fetching student using ExecuteStoreQuery
            var student = objCtx.Database.SqlQuery<Cours>("Select * from Student where StudentName = 'StudentName1'", null).ToList();

        } 

        return View();
    }`
```

Merry Christmas Eve everyone!

Comment: Have you tried `ctx.Database.SqlQuery<T>()` it does almost the same thing as ExecuteStoreCommand

Comment: I have tried it, but I wasn't sure what the difference was and wanted to accurately follow the tutorial.

Is there a comparable method to ExecuteStoreQuery? I'm looking here and I don't see any. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thank you Armand. That did the trick! If anyone needs sample code to work with, all I had to do was change the code to `var student = objCtx.Database.SqlQuery<User>("SELECT * FROM [PM].[dbo].[Users] where Users.UserName = 'uguanch'").ToList();`

Still need to figure out how to read the contents

Answer (score 1):

You need to call method ExecuteSqlCommand(query) for db context "foo" (Not for "foo.Pmentitis")

Example:

```
   using (CompaniesEntities _c = new CompaniesEntities(
                extra.GetCompaniesConnectionString(
                    db_name
                )
            ))
        {

            _c.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"
            if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='agency_templates' and xtype='U')
                CREATE TABLE [dbo].[agency_templates](
                    [ag_templ_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                    ...
            ", new object[] { });
   }
```

Comment: I am doing this though.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you may be using Entity Framework 4, where the Code Generation Strategy was set to "Default" which leads to an ObjectContext being created. Entity Framework 5 on VS2012 creates a DbContext for the data model by default. [How to upgrade EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652920/how-to-upgrade-from-entity-framework-4-3-to-ef-5/12654180#12654180).

Also you can do this:

```
int InsertedRows = (objCtx as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("Insert into students(StudentName,StandardId) values('StudentName1',1)", new object[] { });
```

Comment: No. I was on EF 5 and I just updated to 6. It didn't help, but thank you.